# Can $\tanh(\arctan(x))$ be simplified?

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

Can $\tanh(\arctan(x))$ be simplified or re-expressed in terms of algebraic functions (or maybe a log here and there), kind of like the [forward-inverse identities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTrigonometricFunctions.html)? *(perhaps using the myriad of trig and hyperbolic formulas)*

The only thing I found is the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function), which in some sense yields the opposite of what I need

$$gd(x) = 2 \arctan\left(\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$

Also, when I let Mathematica spit out the MacLaurin series, it seems that $\tan(\arctan(x))$ and $\tanh(\arctan(x))$ have similar expansions (differing only by the usual alternating sign). Is there a place where these kind of relationships between the trigonometric and hyperbolic functions are studied? Anything known about the properties of the coefficients of such series?

Answer (score 2):

How do you feel about 
$$ \tanh \arctan x = \frac{(1-\mathrm{i}x)^\mathrm{i} - (1+\mathrm{i}x)^\mathrm{i}}{(1-\mathrm{i}x)^\mathrm{i} + (1+\mathrm{i}x)^\mathrm{i}}  \text{?}  $$

This is obtained from $\tanh y = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2 y}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{2 y}+1}$ and $\arctan x = \frac{\mathrm{i}}{2} \log \frac{1-\mathrm{i} x}{1+\mathrm{i} x}$, followed by some simplifying.

Comment: How do you get that $i$ symbol like that?  Using a \text block seems clumsy.

Comment: @OscarLanzi : Even worse: "\mathrm{e}"  Similarly for the "$\mathrm{i}$".  It's so common on MSE, I type it automatically now.  (I even forget in my own writing that I long ago created macros in my personal set for these.)

Comment: @Eric Towers: I would prefer something not involving "i" (kind of like the log formulas for the inverse hyperbolic functions), but it seems that such thing may not exist...

Comment: @EricTowers Bless you for putting $\rm e$ and $\rm i$ upright like the true numbers they are